# MySQL Error: [22001][1292] Data truncation: Truncated incorrect time value: ''

Tags: mysql, sql

The following statements works only when all the days have a time interval, not an empty string.

```
SET @active_time = (SELECT active_time FROM parkings WHERE parking_id = 2);
    SET @weekdays = '["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"]';

    UPDATE mytable
    SET is_valid = FALSE,
        status = 'Canceled'
    WHERE (IFNULL(IFNULL(TIME(SUBSTRING_INDEX(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@active_time, CONCAT('$.', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@weekdays, CONCAT('$[', WEEKDAY(arrival_time), ']')))))), '-', 1)), TIME('23:59:59')) > TIME(arrival_time), 1)
        OR IFNULL(IFNULL(TIME(SUBSTRING_INDEX(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@active_time, CONCAT('$.', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@weekdays, CONCAT('$[', WEEKDAY(departure_time), ']')))))), '-', -1)), TIME('00:00:01')) < TIME(departure_time), 1))
        AND parking_id = 2
        AND is_valid
```

I'm getting the error when I run it with lets say "Su" : '' or in other words an empty string. The problem comes from the WHERE clause, I have tried running the following and it works:

```
SET @weekdays = '["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"]';
    SET @active_time = (SELECT active_time FROM parkings WHERE parking_id = 23);
    SELECT TIME(SUBSTRING_INDEX((JSON_EXTRACT(@active_time, CONCAT('$.', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@weekdays, CONCAT('$[', WEEKDAY(departure_time), ']')))))), '-', -1)) FROM mytable;
```

active_time looks like the following when it works:
`{"Fr": "08:00-23:45", "Mo": "05:00-18:00", "Sa": "08:00-20:00", "Su": "08:00-20:00", "Th": "05:00-18:00", "Tu": "05:00-18:00", "We": "05:00-18:00"}`

active_time looks like the following when it doesn't work:
`{"Fr": "08:00-23:45", "Mo": "05:00-18:00", "Sa": "08:00-20:00", "Su": "", "Th": "05:00-18:00", "Tu": "05:00-18:00", "We": "05:00-18:00"}`

I would like to know if someone can tell me why it doesn't works in the first statements but it works in the second group of statements. And if there is another way of doing what I'm trying to do. To simplify the above, the error arises when *TIME('')* happens

Parking table

> ```
> create table parkings
> (
>     parking_id   int auto_increment primary key,
>     parking_name varchar(50)          not null,
>     max_capacity smallint             not null,
>     occupancy    smallint   default 0 not null,
>     pin          varchar(255)         not null,
>     latitude     decimal(8, 6)        not null,
>     longitude    decimal(9, 6)        not null,
>     active_time  json                 null,
>     password     varchar(255)         null,
>     is_valid     tinyint(1) default 1 not null,
>     admin_edited tinyint(1) default 0 null
> );
> ```

Mytable table

> ```
> create table mytable
> (
>     mytable_id int auto_increment primary key,
>     parking_id      int                                   not null,
>     arrival_time    datetime    default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
>     departure_time  datetime    default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
>     capacity        tinyint                               not null,
>     latitude        decimal(8, 6)                         not null,
>     longitude       decimal(9, 6)                         not null,
>     status          varchar(25) default 'Pending'         null,
>     date_created    datetime    default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
>     date_updated    datetime    default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>     is_valid        tinyint(1)  default 1                 not null,
>     foreign key (parking_id) references parkings(parking_id)
> );
> ```

[Sample data as csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTVjkzOWP2yl3Ijv74ACWUt7gaf7d4nNsXBUjQIfmxXQKEaZZ4GReaIwGAoi4OdvrIP5PV-ZLP56lJ7/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv)

Comment: Give us table structure for `parkings` and sample data to work with.

Comment: Hi, I just added what you ask me. Let me know if it works

Comment: You should re-post those table structures as text format.. just like the query you've posted .. because it's almost likely that we'll need to copy and paste everything in a fiddle or our own database to do test runs and rewriting everything from images is one thing we certainly want to avoid.

Comment: Hi sorry for that, I just updated it and include this time the queries to create the tables